# Concrete 5 theme installation issue with absent required files

Tags: php, content-management-system, content-management, concrete5

I have installed Concrete 5.5.2.1 and i'm now attempting to install a theme I have downloaded from the marketplace.

I have downloaded the zip archive, extracted it and FTP'd the full directory up to the /themes directory. However, after trying a couple of themes I get this error everytime:

> File /htdocs/concrete5.5.2.1/themes/cannonf700_zenlike/default.php not
>   found. All themes need default.php and view.php files in them. Consult
>   concrete5 documentation on how to create these files.

Both themes appear to have these files and I have not changed any code, files or structure before uploading.

Is there an issue with the theme of the way I am uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this answered my question:

http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/themes/importing-a-theme/...

I had to upload to the /packages dir, not /themes. From there, i could then install through the 'Add Functionality' menu option..